# iTextsharp, PdfPCell.VerticalAlignment and PdfPCell.HorizontalAlignment

Tags: c#, itext, cell, vertical-alignment

Im trying to figure out how to get my text inside a PdfPCell to show in the middle. I have tried many different options, like:

```
myCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
myCell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
myCell.VerticalAlignment = Rectangle.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
```

None of that works for me. VerticalAlignment takes an int, so I tried to make a loop, to see if i could find the right number, but everything just get left bottom align..

```
   Document myDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4);

   PdfWriter myPdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, new FileStream(strPDFFilePath, FileMode.Create));
   myDocument.Open();

   myDocument.NewPage();

   PdfContentByte myPdfContentByte = myPdfWriter.DirectContent;

   PdfPCell myCell;
   Paragraph myParagraph;

   PdfPTable myTable = new PdfPTable(4);
   myTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
   myTable.SetWidths(new int[4] { 25, 25, 25, 25 });

   myTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;
   myTable.DefaultCell.BorderColor = BaseColor.RED;                

   for (int i = -100; i < 100; i++)
   {
       myParagraph = new Paragraph(String.Format("Alignment: {0}", i));
       myParagraph.Font.SetFamily("Verdana");
       myParagraph.Font.SetColor(72, 72, 72);
       myParagraph.Font.Size = 11;

       myCell = new PdfPCell();
       myCell.AddElement(myParagraph);
       myCell.HorizontalAlignment = i;
       myCell.VerticalAlignment = i;                    
       myTable.AddCell(myCell);
   }

   myDocument.Add(myTable);
   myDocument.Add(new Chunk(String.Empty));
   myDocument.Close();
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think the basic problem you're having is that you're adding text to iTextSharp `Paragraph` objects and then attempting to set this text's alignment using the `PdfPCell` object that contains it.  I'm not sure if the `PdfPCell.VerticalAlignment` property is only for a `PdfPCell`'s text, or if aligning the `Paragraph` object inside the `PdfPCell` doesn't have any affect you can see in your test.

You're also setting `myCell.HorizontalAlignment` and `myCell.VerticalAlignment` to the index value in your `for` loop. I think you meant to use 1 instread of `i`.

Anyway, setting a PdfPCell's `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties do work though.  Below is a small method that demonstrates this.  I wrote it very loosely based on what you were trying to do; if it's close enough to what you're trying to do perhaps you can use this as a starting point in your project.

```
private void TestTableCreation() {
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("TableTest.pdf", FileMode.Create)) {
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
        doc.Open();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);

        for (int i = -100; i < 100; i++) {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.Format("Alignment: {0}", i)));
            // Give our rows some height so we can see test vertical alignment.
            cell.FixedHeight = 30.0f;

            // ** Try it **
            //cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            //cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

            cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
            //cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            //cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;

            table.AddCell(cell);
        }

        doc.Add(table);
        doc.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked better when i started to use Phrase instead of Paragraph

Answer (score 7):

Jay Riggs solution started to work also for vertical alignment when I added:

`cell.UseAscender = true;`

http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs-itextsharp/html/0602b79e-ea9c-0c7d-c4b2-bc4b5f976f15.htm

Answer (score 3):

I tried giving direct integers and other solutions mentioned here. But nothing worked for me. A combination of this worked for me in Composition method.

```
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use given code, i hope i will be most helpful for those who want to print a text in a cell in middle and top alignment 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gettable();
        }

```
    void gettable()
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Vedic-Chart-Life-Report.pdf"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
        {

            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
            doc.Open();
            doc.NewPage();

            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont("C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/krdv010.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            Font f = new Font(bf, 16, Font.BOLD);

            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

            cb.MoveTo(0, doc.PageSize.Height - 20);
            cb.LineTo(doc.PageSize.Width, doc.PageSize.Height - 20);
            cb.Stroke();
            cb.ClosePathStroke();

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("eaxynks'k foospu", f));

            // Give our rows some height so we can see test vertical alignment.
            cell.FixedHeight = 15f;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;

            table.AddCell(cell);
            doc.Add(table);

            //cb.RoundRectangle(10f, 550f, 592f, 200f, 20f);
            //cb.Stroke();

            //doc.Add(new Phrase("eaxynks'k foospu", f));

            doc.Close();
        }

    }
```